# wipe/wipes, is correct in this sentence?

Tags: word-choice, grammar

In this sentence two characters only.

“*Barlo finds the sheep wipe[s] his tears.*”. Do I need to add "S" for "wipe" or not ? and Why ?

Comment: Voting to migrate to English SE, because I feel that a question about grammar fits there.

Comment: @Sciborg: It would be rejected by both ELU and ELL for showing no evidence of research.  Migration would be pointless.

Comment: How many sheep?